# transacciones usando SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, transacciones, ado.net

estoy haciendo una sencilla aplicación usando ADO.NET Y necesito hacer una transacción por si me falla un `insert`, pero estoy usando `sqlCommandBuider` para construir el `command` y no encuentro nada de información al respecto para usar Transacciones con este, si para hacerlas con un `SqlCommand`, pero no con un `SqlCommandBuilder`.
¿Alguien me puede echar un cable por favor ?

EDIT:
Intentando hacerlo como me sugiere @VRoxa:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT num,Ejercici,Serie,CClient,Adress,CP,Provincia " +
         $"FROM t_cabecera", conn);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
```

Me salta el error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
>   en la linea: `adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;`

EDIT2:
Con el siguiente código:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT num,Ejercici,Serie,CClient,Adress,CP,Provincia FROM t_cabecera", conn);
        var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        var builder = CreateAttachBuilder(adapter, transaction);
        try
        {
            foreach (Order order in Lorders)
            {
                var insertCmd = builder.GetInsertCommand(true);
                // insertCmd.Parameters["@IdDocumento"].Value = Funcions.creaGUID(order.number.ToString());
                insertCmd.Parameters["@num"].Value = order.number;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@Ejercici"].Value = GlobalVar.Ejercicio;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@Serie"].Value = GlobalVar.SerieDocumento;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@CClient"].Value = order.customer_id.ToString();
                insertCmd.Parameters["@Adress"].Value = GlobalVar.Empresa;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@CP"].Value = trencaCadena(order.billing.address_1,40);
                insertCmd.Parameters["@Provincia"].Value = order.billing.city;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@CodigoPostal"].Value = order.billing.postcode;
                insertCmd.Parameters["@Provincia"].Value = order.billing.state;
                insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            errormessage = ex.Message.ToString();
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        scope.Complete()
        return result;
    }
}
```

Si hay un catch, es decir un `transaction.Rollback()`; me salta el error:

> SqlException: La solicitud COMMIT TRANSACTION no tiene la
>   correspondiente BEGIN TRANSACTION.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Estás usando un `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: Si, así  es, es donde defino la consulta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando el `SqlDataAdapter`, puedes dar valor a la propiedad `Transaction` de cada una de los `Command` del *adapter*.

Creamos la transacción de forma normal...

```
string connectionString = "...";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

conn.Open();

// Creamos la transaccion en la SqlConnection
SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
```

Una vez tengamos el objeto de la transacción, podremos modificar cada uno de los `Command` del `SqlCommandBuilder` con esa instancia.

```
public SqlDataAdapter AttachTransaction(SqlDataAdapter adapter, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
   adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;
   adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
   adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
}
```

De este modo ya podemos controlar todos los comandos del `SqlDataAdapter` asociados a nuestra transacción.

```
// ...

adapter = AttachTransaction(adapter, transaction);

try
{
   // Hacemos el trabajo que queramos
   // Pudiendo hacer cualquier transaction.Commit
}
catch
{
   // Por ejemplo...
   transaction.Rollback();
}
```

El código que he puesto es sólo un ejemplo. Hay mil formas de hacerlo de una manera mejor. Sobretodo teniendo en cuenta que quizás sólo te interesa controlar por transacción los comandos de un tipo concreto (*insert*, *delete*, ...) o incluso que varias transacciones sean las que controlen los diferentes comandos. Dependerá mucho de tus necesitades.

**EDIT:** Uso del `SqlCommandBuilder`

Dos formas de hacerlo, realmente. Ambas tienen en cuenta la clase [`TransactionScope`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1).

1. Usar directamente el `TransactionScope` como instancia de transacción.
   El `TransactionScope` va a garantir que todo el bloque de código dentro de su *scope* sea considerado como una única *unit of work*.

```
public void Scope(Action<TransactionScope> action)
{
    using var scope = new TransactionScope();

    try
    {
        action(scope);

        // La llamada a Complete
        // va a hacer el commit de la action
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Si action propaga alguna excepción
        // la unidad de trabajo queda sin completar
    }
}
```

2. Crear `SqlTransaction` explícitas.
   De este modo puedes controlar de forma más segura los `Commit` y `Rollback` dentro de la unidad de trabajo, invocándolos cuando necesites y sin necesidad de que todo el bloque termine su trabajo.
   También permitirá, como mencionaba, controlar de forma individual las operaciones dentro del `DataSet` asignando diferentes `SqlTransaction` a cada una de ellas.

```
public SqlCommandBuilder CreateAttachedBuilder(SqlDataAdapter adapter, 
                                               SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    var cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    cb.GetInsertCommand().Transaction = transaction;
    cb.GetDeleteCommand().Transaction = transaction;
    cb.GetUpdateCommand().Transaction = transaction;

    return cb;
}
```

Haciendo uso de un `SqlCommandBuilder`, podemos acceder a cada uno de los `SqlCommand` para las diferentes operaciones con los métodos `Get...Command` y asignar la instancia de la `SqlTransaction`.

```
public void PerformWork(string connectionString, string selectCommand)
{
    void Action(TransactionScope scope)
    {
        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        // ...

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);

        var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        // Creamos el SqlCommandBuilder asociado a la transaccion
        var cb = CreateAttachedBuilder(adapter, transaction);

        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch
        {
            // i.e.
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    // Ejecutamos la unidad de trabajo
    // Aislada bajo el scope transaccional
    Scope(Action);
}
```

Por si causa alguna duda, estoy usando *C#8.0*, por eso declaro de ese modo los `using`.

**EDIT 2:** Usando C#7 y sin `Action<>`.
Te dejo aquí todo el código en una misma función para que no te dé problema.

```
public void Work(string connectionString, string selectCommand)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                // ...

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);

                var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                // Creamos el SqlCommandBuilder asociado a la transaccion
                var cb = CreateAttachedBuilder(adapter, transaction);

                try
                {
                    // ...
                }
                catch
                {
                    // i.e.
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

            // La llamada a Complete
            // va a hacer el commit de la action
            scope.Complete();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Si action propaga alguna excepción
            // la unidad de trabajo queda sin completar
        }
    }
}
```

Resulta siendo el mismo código pero con varios niveles de profundidad y bastante más largo... Por eso lo separé en dos.

Considero que sí, debe ser otra pregunta, por eso no explico qué o por qué. Sólo te doy el código sin el `Action<>`.  Te dejo [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1) la documentación.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Hola @VRoxa, primero gracias.
Me genera un error, edito mi pregunta para pegar código, no se si es el modo de proceder.

Comment: @MiguelAngel Debes instanciar un `SqlCommand` y *setear* la *property* `InsertCommand` con esta instancia. Una vez hecho eso, le asignas la transacción creada. [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) te dejo la documentación oficial de MS. Por norma general, la instanciación del `SqlDataAdapter` está aislada del consumo de ésta. Es ahí donde deberías hacerle el *attach* a la transacción.

Comment: Comprendo, pero como decía en mi pregunta, no estoy haciendo uso de `SqlCommand`, sino de `SqlCommandBuilder` y de su método `GetInsertCommand`.

Comment: Sé que debería pertenecer a otra pregunta, pero podrías aclararme la instrucción `Scope(Action);` por favor, me da error en probarla y tampoco entiendo que es lo que hace, le estás pasando un método a una transacción pasada como parámetro al mismo método al que llamas?
Perdona por mi ignorancia, pero no lo entiendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias VRoxa, te agradezco tu ayuda, aunque no lo lo conozco con profundidad, si conozco el delegado `Action<>`, pero no logro entender la manera como lo defines en el punto nº2 ya que parece que estás declarando un método y no un delegado.

Comment: Es una funcionalidad de C#7. Es práticamente lo mismo, le denominan funciones locales y actúan como delegados, pero no están asignadas a una variable como tal. El compilador las puede tomar como `Action<>`.

Comment: VRoxa, soy extremadamente cansino, pero me siguen sin funcionar, parece que va todo bien, pero no me inserta nada en la tabla, ¿qué hago mal?. Edito mi pregunta y perdona.

Comment: En referéncia al mi ultimo comentario, el error que me dispara al hacer el transaction.Rollback(), eliminando el este, funciona correctamente, ¿porqué?

Comment: Nunca me he encontrado este error. Pero parece ser que es porque al haber hecho el `transaction.Rollback`, si después intenta hacer el `scope.Complete` falla porque no hay nada a *commitear*. Es decir, el `scope.Complete` sólo se podrá hacer si no ha habido ninguna `SqlException`. Prueba con eso y me comentas porque como digo, nunca me he enfrentado a este error.

Comment: Era exactamente por eso VRoxa, muchas gracias por todo.